# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend changeable in-app?

Tags: iphone

Ok, so we all are aware (or should be) that 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' can be set true or false in the info.plist file.

What I would like to know please, if possible, is if we can change the bool value of UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend  in app.

Simply allowing the user to set whether the app is allowed to run in background, or wether it should just kill itself on the pressing of the home button.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the value in the app.

However you could add a setting to your app and check wheter it's on/off in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.
Something like:

```
if (theUserDoesNotWantMultitasking) {
    exit(0); // doesn't generate a crash report.
}
```

It seems tolerated by Apple validation process even though I bet they're not recommending it.

Small precision:
By *tolerated*, I mean that I've done that once in an app, with a different use case (not based on a user setting). It has been approved, but I can't guarantee that it will always be the case.

Comment: "it seems tolerated" -- have you personally seen an app get through the app review process that contains exit(0)? I thought Apple's static analyzer would pick up on it. Apple firmly say to not exit your app; it's down to the user to press the Home button when they want to use a different app.

Comment: @occulus Yes. One of the apps I worked on uses it (but not with the same use case). Technically, the `exit` is done after the user pressed the Home button (**didEnter**Background). It's not exactly the same way as doing an `exit(0)` at a random location in the app.

Comment: I like your way of thinking - ill give it a try any way as it does  what I want it to (when used in correct context) and if rejected then so be it. Also very true about  (**didEnter**Background).

Comment: I did something similar. I showed a UIAlert `Serious problem blabla. Can only be resolved by exiting the app. when you press ok the app will exit.` and when Ok is tapped I do the exit(0) thing. If you look through apple documentation there are various places where they say you should inform the user and tell him to press the homebutton. Since this doesn't work with multitasking I went for the exit(0) way. It doesn't happen often, best way it should never happen. And app is in the store. I guess they haven't seen it, because it never happens. But I didn't want to ask them for obvious reason.

Comment: I can confirm that Apple doesn't reject a random `exit(0)` call: my app was doing that to force switch a language right after `UIAlert`, without asking for the Home button pressing. It passed initial review and a few updates.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

Calling `exit` from your app is going against Apple's advice. If you do so, you may find your app rejected at some future point.

Read the best practices: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html

Comment: hey - thanks for the link - some useful (and some obvious) tips in there. :)